# FluentMigrator Syntax error executing PostgreSql function

Tags: c#, postgresql, syntax-error, fluent-migrator

it's not the first time that I encountered this problem.
When I have to do a migration of my `Postgres` database and I have to create some function, I always have problems with the syntax accepted by `FluentMigrator` `Migration` and they are usually related to " or '.

An example is the following function:

```
DROP FUNCTION public.generate_csv_of_typology(IN typology integer)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_csv_of_typology(IN typology integer)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE 
AS $function$
DECLARE r RECORD;
DECLARE ro RECORD;
DECLARE rf RECORD;
DECLARE nAn bigint;
DECLARE nRoi bigint;
DECLARE nf bigint;
DECLARE iA int = 0;
DECLARE iR int = 0;
DECLARE iFormato int = 0;
DECLARE nAnalisiFormato int = 0;
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS formati;
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE formati AS SELECT DISTINCT nome_formato FROM pezzo';
nf := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM formati);

FOR rf IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM formati'
LOOP
    iFormato := iFormato + 1;
    raise notice '------- n formato: (% - %) -------', iFormato, nf;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS analisiFormato;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE analisiFormato AS SELECT analisi.id, pezzo_id, num_vista, tipologia, esito, liv_errore, analisi.created_at, analisi.updated_at FROM analisi JOIN pezzo ON analisi.pezzo_id = pezzo.id WHERE pezzo.nome_formato = '''||rf.nome_formato::text||''' ';
    nAnalisiFormato := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM analisiFormato);
    raise notice '------- n analisi del formato %: % -------', rf.nome_formato::text, nAnalisiFormato;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numvista;    
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE numvista AS SELECT DISTINCT num_vista FROM analisiFormato';

    FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM numvista'
    LOOP   
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oiddistinct;  
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE oiddistinct AS select distinct oid from analisiFormato join area on analisiFormato.id = area.analisi_id AND analisiFormato.num_vista = '||r.num_vista::text||' AND analisiFormato.tipologia = '||typology::integer;
        nRoi := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oiddistinct);
        FOR ro IN EXECUTE 'SELECT oid FROM oiddistinct'
        LOOP       
            raise notice '------- n roi: (% - %) -------', iR, nRoi;
            EXECUTE 'COPY
            (
                SELECT area.created_at, area.risultato_analisi, area.updated_at FROM area
                    join analisiFormato on area.analisi_id = analisiFormato.id
                    WHERE oid = '''||ro.oid::text||''' ORDER BY area.created_at 
            ) TO ''C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/Formato'||rf.nome_formato::text||'NumVista'||r.num_vista::text||'-'||ro.oid::text||'.csv'' WITH CSV;';
            iR := iR + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    PERFORM pg_sleep(3);
END LOOP;
END;

$function$;
```

This function is read from a file and executed with the command

```
Execute.Sql(functionDefinition);
```

The error is:

```
error 42601 syntax error at or near 'CREATE'
```

I tried to add other ' and it goes. I think I'm missing something but I didn't find any information about this. Does anyone know if there are any rules about how execute a npgsql function during a migration with FluentMigrator?

Comment: you drop table with `drop` statement. what makes you wrap `create table` to execute argument if there is no dynamic sql?..

Comment: You have no `;` after `DROP FUNCTION` but before `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`.

Comment: You're right! I missed it! I was too focused on the migrator.